# How to get broadcast address with python socket in localhost?

Tags: python, sockets

I try to send messages in localhost to broadcast address, but it does not work. When I use `socket.INADDR_BROADCAST`, I get `[Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed`.

```py
import socket


client_server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client_server.bind(("127.0.0.1", 12345))
client_server.connect((f"{socket.INADDR_BROADCAST}", 12345))

client_server.sendto("New user is connected".encode("utf-8"), (f"{socket.INADDR_BROADCAST}", 12345))
```

Comment: Your title does not match your code.  *Getting* a broadcast IP, and *using* a broadcast IP, are two very different things.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a TCP (`SOCK_STREAM`) socket. TCP has no notion of broadcasting. A TCP client socket cannot `connect()` to a broadcast IP, and a TCP server socket cannot `listen()` on a broadcast IP. That just makes no sense to do.  The only way to broadcast a message in TCP is for the server to keep track of each client connected to it and then send the message to each client one at a time.

A UDP (`SOCK_DGRAM`) socket, on the other hand, can `sendto()` a message to a broadcast IP (if you enable the socket's `SO_BROADCAST` option beforehand), and it can `recvfrom()` a message that was sent to a broadcast IP belonging to the adapter that the socket is bound to.

Just note that `bind()`'ing a broadcasting UDP socket to `127.0.0.1` means that only UDP receivers also bound to `127.0.0.1` will be able to receive the broadcasts. You won't be able to broadcast over the network.

```
import socket

client_server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
#client_server.bind(("127.0.0.1", 12345))
client_server.setsockopt(client_server.SOL_SOCKET, client_server.SO_BROADCAST, 1)

client_server.sendto("New user is connected".encode("utf-8"), (f"{socket.INADDR_BROADCAST}", 12345))
```